# How to enable venv to access pygame module in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, python-venv

I am trying to learn Python by following the book "Python Crash Course",
but I'm stuck because the book does not use the IDE I am using, PyCharm.

The problem I encounter is when I try to import pygame it says `module not found`.

I successfully installed pygame using this command:

```
python -m pip install --user pygame
```

[command prompt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4huZM.jpg)

I get the message "successfully installed pygame"

but I'm still unable to import it. I noticed that PyCharm uses the interpreter from this location: `\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe`

which is inside the project folder.

My python is installed in:

`\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe`

How can I give PyCharm's virtual environment access to pygame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change your project interpreter of pycharm

got to File -> Setting -> your_project -> project interpreter

and then select the Venv where you have installed your required library.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks om! this works but what I actually want is to install the pygame into my venv as well.

Comment: there is a plus sign in the right side as you can see in the screenshot from there you can install it.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the package from the project interpreter given in pycharm

Answer (score 1):

```
PyCharm -> Prefrences -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> Add Local
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your suggestions, Both jackotonye and om tripathi's answer are correct I just prefer jackotonye's but instead of 'add local' I install pygame module

Here's what I did, on PyCharm to go:

```
File -> Settings -> Project: HelloWorld -> Project Interpreter -> '+' (plus sign)
```

this will allow you to install packages/module in your venv.

but I think you will have to do this for every project you will create unless you selected "Default Settings" instead of "Settings" on the above instruction I stated.

PS: om tripathi's answer works as well, changing the interpreter to my native python instead of the venv's python.

Thanks!